# Which gradle task builds AndroidTest .*apk and doesn't do anything additional

Tags: android, gradle, apk

Let's say I have a build variant named `debugAutomation`.

I wan't to build this variant into .*apk file using gradle command. I do:

```
./gradlew assembleDebugAutomation
```

This provides me with application .*apk. But to perform automation tests in espresso I also need test .*apk. So I do again:

```
./gradlew assembleDebugAutomationAndroidTest
```

And .*apk with `-androidTest` is in my `outputs/apk/` folder of my project.

Where is the trick and problem?

a) while performing `assembleDebugAutomation` I have only application .*apk built.

b) while performing `assembleDebugAutomationAndroidTest` then during build process THIS APK BEING INSTALLED ON ALL CURRENTLY VISIBLE DEVICES IN ADB.

My question is: How can I build `androidTest` .*apk with gradle command so it ONLY BUILDS APK and DOESN'T INSTALL IT on currently visible devices in ADB during build process?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you need? If you need to just create an apk use `./gradlew assembleDebug`, it will build and create an APK.

Comment: Hello, I have made edit and stated clear question.

Answer (score 2):

To just assemble into an APK:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

That will build however, but won't do any automation tests, nor would it install to devices.

Comment: This is not correct. Check this log and line 146. 
https://gist.github.com/FisherKK/51caa6f92571bcae13387bc1552f3084

Comment: Check your first line `gradlew -p /Users/F1sherKK/Dev/MyApp/ assembleAutomationIntegrationTestAndroidTest`
You used your command, not mine.

Comment: `assembleAutomationIntegrationTestAndroidTest` is a task generated by gradle for building `AndroidTest` apk for my flavour `automationIntegrationTest`. I don't want to build debug. I want to build .*apk for specific flavour/build-variant.

Comment: Can you post the gradle configuration for your builds and flavours?

Comment: Also add the task configurations you have. `assemble` never installs to the device by its own.

Comment: Give me a second please. I will post something in few mins.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/FisherKK/e866b5f734f9b337401b316ba40c583e build.gradle of my project

Comment: You do not have `AndroidTest` build type, you have `integrationTest` and `automation` flavour. Use `./gradlew assembleAutomationIntegrationTest`

Comment: Otherwise, I'd recommend renaming your build types and flavours to not include "Test" word.

Comment: But `./gradlew assembleAutomationIntegrationTest` will build .apk containing application that I want to test.

I need another .apk. One that contains tests. Android Automation test process needs 2 apks -> application apk, and test apk. You run test apk against application apk. 

`./gradlew assembleAutomationIntegrationTest` this will build for me only application apk. 

When I start test in Android Studio it does:
`Executing tasks: [:app:assembleAutomationIntegrationTest, :app:assembleAutomationIntegrationTestAndroidTest]`

But first task only builds apk, second one also installs.

Comment: And after gradle tasks are executed Android Studio executes shell command to Adb and installs the same apk which was already installed during build process (which I dont want to happen).

Answer (score 1):

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Builds the debug APK.

```
./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest
```

Builds the test APK

Or if you have a flavour in your gradle file it would be:

```
./gradlew assemble<FlavourName>DebugAndroidTest
```